# How should I understand "followed by"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> This time you put the big rocks in the bucket first, followed by
>   pebbles.

I know the meaning of this sentence, but I don't know the structure of this sentence because of "followed by."

How can I rephrase this sentence to explain?

What's omitted between "first" and "followed by" ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's just a way of saying that one thing happens/comes after the other thing. So this sentence can be rephrased as, "This time you put the big rock in the bucket first, 'and then' the pebbles."

Comment: There's also an implicit parallelism: "This time you put the big rock in the bucket, and then [you put] the pebbles [in the bucket]."

Comment: While I'm aware of that, I think both of our sentences are grammatically correct.